# Is it possible to put a function within a constraint in Julia?

Tags: optimization, julia, linear-programming, gurobi, julia-jump

I'm using Julia with JuMP and Gurobi to solve an optimisation problem.

Two of my constraints have "if/else" like properties. I need values to be less than the sum of to real numbers but if the real number is larger than one I need it to be equal to one.

I made a function which returns the sum if they are smaller than one and the sum if they are not. I did a similar solution to my other constraint.

```
@constraint(m, [l in Locations, i in Locations, r in Rotor_size, wd in WD],
        wake_rot[l, wd, r] <=   isone(wake_loc, wd, l, i, r))
```

with isone is

```
function isone(wake_loc, wd, l, i, r)

   a = wake_loc[wd, l, i] + Adj_wake[r]

   if a > 1
       return 1
   else
       return a
   end
end
```

My model is unbounded(or infeasible) and I'm wondering if this can be the the source to my problems.

Comment: I think your constraint is correct. The fact that your model is infeasible doesn't seem to be linked to a wrong formulation of this constraint. One possibility now, is to try to comment each constraint until your model becomes feasible to see which one may be wrong.

Comment: Are all the arguments to your `isone` function (`wake_loc`, `wd`, etc.) parameters, as opposed to decision variables? I don't think any can be decision variables, but I suspect JuMP would have yelled at you if you had done that.

Comment: Also, it might be cleaner and easier to debug if you just define a new parameter like `RHS[l,i,r,wd] = wake_loc[wd, l, i] + Adj_wake[r]` and just use that in your right-hand side, instead of a function.